# How to remove youtube application from launcher?

Tags: firefox, launcher, uninstall, youtube

the first time i visited Youtube with Firexox, it asked me to install Youtube launcher application, i've accepted but now I want to remove it.
Every time I open youtube.com in Firefox, also appear a Youtube application button in the launcher. If I right-click on the button i can only block it on the launcher, open a new tab or quit, how can I remove it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove these files.

```bsh
rm ~/.local/share/applications/YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop
sudo rm /usr/share/applications/YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop
```

Or, maybe better, keep a copy of them by using `mv` instead `rm`:

```bsh
mv ~/.local/share/applications/YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop.bak
sudo mv /usr/share/applications/YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop /usr/share/applications/YouTubeyoutubecom.desktop.bak
```